# Return rundeck script variables after calling job from httpResponse

Tags: jenkins, rundeck

I'm calling a Rundeck job using Jenkins

```
def response = httpRequest(url: url,
                               httpMode: 'POST',
                               contentType: 'APPLICATION_JSON',
                               requestBody: request_json_str,
                               customHeaders: rundeckHeaders)

def json_resp = readJSON text: response.content
```

How do I include variables from Rundeck script in response.content?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to call Rundeck jobs from Jenkins is to use the Rundeck Plugin available [here](https://plugins.jenkins.io/rundeck/) (and downloadable on the Jenkins plugins manager).

1. In Jenkins, download the Rundeck plugin from the plugin manager.
2. Configure the plugin: go to "Manage Jenkins" > "Configure System" > Rundeck section (put the Rundeck instance info, you have two options to link the Rundeck instance, via API key or just passing the user/password) and save. Take a [look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iwcqc.jpg).
3. On your pipeline configuration, scroll down and choose "Post-build actions", select your Rundeck instance configured in the previous step, and put the Job ID that would want to run from Jenkins. In the options section, you can call any option with the format `myoption = myvalue`, take a [look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xhi6Q.jpg).
4. Run your pipeline and see the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iUHq.jpg) on the Rundeck instance activity page.

Comment: I am able to call the rundeck job from thew Jenkins pipeline, but Rundeck decides what it sends back to the httpRequest. I need to modify that json return.

Comment: Do you want to see the option's value in the Rundeck response right?

Comment: Reading options might do the trick. Quick question though, in the example shown looks like you are assigning the option a value `opt1=jenkins` and not reading `opt1`

Comment: yes, because the option value is passed via the Jenkins plugin, not sure what you mean by "and not reading opt1".

Comment: I want to be able to return a value from Rundeck to Jenkins, not the other way around.